# Load html in window , what the substitute for thus code ,it keep giving me security alert

Tags: javascript, html, electron

it keep giving me this , and it dont load anything on the main window

> Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
>       Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
>       this app to unnecessary security risks.

```
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes:true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). Since you are using `file://` protocol you can simply add the following line under the `head` section in `mainWindow.html`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

You can find out more details about CSP in Electron in [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md#6-define-a-content-security-policy)